# Call SQLiteOpenHelper method from fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

i want to call this method getAllData(); from Fragment, this method return cursor data from SQlite Database and i want to use that data inside my Fragment to create listView, i use these lines of code to access that data

```
PackagesDbHelper mydb = new PackagesDbHelper(getActivity());
Cursor result = mydb.getAllData();
```

but on app launch i get this error "unfortunately app has stopped" but if i exclude this line of code

```
Cursor result = mydb.getAllData();
```

my app works fine

PackagesDbHelper

```
public class PackagesDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PackagesContract.ufoneEntry.TABLE_NAME, null);
    return result;
}
```

}

PackagesFragment

```
public class PackagesFragment extends Fragment {

private PackagesAdapter packagesAdapter;
PackagesDbHelper mydb = new PackagesDbHelper(getActivity());

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Cursor result = mydb.getAllData();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
PackagesDbHelper mydb = new PackagesDbHelper(getActivity());
```

line causing issue because calling `getActivity()` at class level will return invalid Activity Context.

Initialize `mydb` object inside `onCreate` or any other method :

```
mydb = new PackagesDbHelper(getActivity());
Cursor result = mydb.getAllData();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

this method should be call by context.

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = context.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PackagesContract.ufoneEntry.TABLE_NAME, null);
    return result; 
}
```